# NSString drawInRect with 2 different font style

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this following text coming from server. i need to change the font style depending on the result before sending out to the printer from device.

1.
Driver
Id #123445
Verified

2.
Driver
Id #123445
**UNVERIFIED**

if text has `UNVERIFIED` i need to bold that unverified text part.

currently i do following to create image

```
   CGRect text10Rect = CGRectMake(DateTextRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 40, DateTextRect.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 20 - 10);
        [strokeColor setFill];
 [stringFromServer drawInRect: text10Rect withFont: smallFont lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

i was thinking checking if it has `UNVERIFIED` then apply `bold` font to it. but couldnt figure out good way to do that.

Comment: Use an `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

I endedup doing following method.

```
if([stringFromServer containsString:@"UNVERIFIED"]){
            stringFromServer = [firstBlock stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"UNVERIFIED" withString:@""];

            CGRect text10Rect = CGRectMake(DateTextRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 40, DateTextRect.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 20 - 10);
            [strokeColor setFill];
            [stringFromServer drawInRect: text10Rect withFont: smallFont lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            CGRect text11Rect = CGRectMake(DateTextRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 130, DateTextRect.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 20 - 10);
            [strokeColor setFill];
            [@"UNVERIFIED" drawInRect: text11Rect withFont: smallFontBold lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        }else{
            CGRect text10Rect = CGRectMake(DateTextRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 40, DateTextRect.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(DateTextRect) + 20 - 10);
            [strokeColor setFill];
            [stringFromServer drawInRect: text10Rect withFont: smallFont lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        }
```

Comment: This is the hard way. Why not use `NSAttributedString? Then you don't need three rect, three colors, and three calls to `drawInRect`.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` has a `drawInRect` method. It just has slightly different parameters.